# Am I trying to create a Loop?

Tags: excel, vba

I have recorded a macro in which I run Solver.

Set Objective $F$10 to Min

By Changing $F$10

Constraints:
$DB$97<=20
$FB$10>=0

I would like to alter the VBA code such that the function repeats for different cell references. However, I am very new to this and not quite sure where to go from here. I THINK the proper terminology here is that I want to create a loop. I would appreciate any guidance or direction.

I have only started attempting to learn VBA. I have VBA for Modelers 5th edition as a reference.

```
Sub PleaseWork()
'
' PleaseWork Macro
'

'
    SolverOk SetCell:="$F$10", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$F$10", Engine _
        :=3, EngineDesc:="Evolutionary"
    SolverOk SetCell:="$F$10", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$F$10", Engine _
        :=3, EngineDesc:="Evolutionary"
    SolverSolve
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-6
End Sub
```

Specifically, I would like for the next iteration to replace "$F$10" with "$F$11"...

1. The SolverOK code seems redundant here.
2. There seems to be a missing piece of code. $DB$97 is set to <= 20 in Solver, but is not present in the recorded macro code. I would also like the next iteration to replace $DB$97 with $DC$98...

Comment: Looks like a job for a loop, yes. You want to wrap that code with a `For` loop and replace that hard-coded `10` with a concatenation of `"$F$"` and the current counter value, assuming you make it start at `10`, e.g. `For i = 10 To 20`, then you can do `SetCell:="$F$" & i`

Comment: Thank you Mathieu. That was incredibly helpful. For the missing constraint $DB$97<=20, am I on the right track in thinking that I need to do something with the offset or change funtions? Of course, I need to place the constraint in the code to being with using SolverAdd.